# Transitioning to Swashbuckle 5.0

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swagger via Swashbuckle V4, having the Endpoints Authenticated by the use of an API KEY.

The following configuration works perfectly when using Swashbuckle V4 (Please note, only the Swagger code is shown):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

 services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  c.SwaggerDoc(
   "v1",
   new Info {
    Title = "OAPI", Version = "v1"
   });
  c.AddSecurityDefinition("api_key", new ApiKeyScheme {
    In = "query",
    Description = "Please Enter Authentication Token",
    Name = "key",
    Type = "apiKey"
  });
  c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary < string, IEnumerable < string >> {
   {
    "api_key",
    new [] {
     "readAccess",
     "writeAccess"
    }
   }
  });
 });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

 app.UseSwagger();

 app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/api/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
  c.RoutePrefix = "api/swagger";
 });
}
```

The Swashbuckle [GitHub page](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle), contains a "*Transitioning to Swashbuckle 5.0*" topic, but it does not cover the use of an API Key.

I wasn't able to found a complete example on how to transition to V5, so i analysed the Method signatures in order to produce the same configuration.

The following code pretends to replicate the above V4 configuration:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

 var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
   In = ParameterLocation.Query,
   Description = "Please Enter Authentication Token",
   Name = "key",
   Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
 };

 services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  c.SwaggerDoc("V1", new OpenApiInfo {
    Version = "V1",
    Title = "API",
    Description = "API"
  });

  c.AddSecurityDefinition("api_key", securityScheme);

  c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
   {
    securityScheme,
    new [] {
     "readAccess",
     "writeAccess"
    }
   }
  });

  c.EnableAnnotations();
 });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

 app.UseSwagger();

 app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/api/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
  c.RoutePrefix = "api/swagger";
 });
}
```

When running the API, the Swagger Authentication window is presented, and i'm able to Authenticate using the API KEY.

Unfortunately, when executing any Endpoint, i receive the following error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync]
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke
        at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke
        at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore
```

I assume there is something i'm missing, i have tried to research on the *[Microsoft.OpenApi.Models](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/tree/master/src/Microsoft.OpenApi/Models)* classes, but so far i had no luck. Its probably a small detail, but hadn't been able to understand it so far ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the scheme when using `AddSecurityRequirement` since you're applying it globally.
Also the array of scopes must be empty when using any other type than "oauth2".

The following example should work.

```cs
c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Id = "api_key",
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                            }
                        },
                        new List<string>() }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to do what @Pavlos said, you need to specify default authenticationScheme by use AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme).
for example:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

Or specify authorizeData in RequireAuthorization method.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers()
        .RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute() { AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme });
});
```

and you can use multiple AuthenticationSchemes, join them by comma.